# can't print from nested foreach loop in php

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

There's four arrays and four foreach loops. Two foreach within other two foreach loops, and i want to echo an array value from nested foreach loop. But i don't know why this prints nothing in my browser.

```
  $abc = array('arif'=>50, 'mofiz'=> 60, 'tofiz'=> 90);
  $def = array('arif'=>55, 'mofiz'=> 65, 'tofiz'=> 95);
  $ghi = array('arif'=>58, 'mofiz'=> 68, 'tofiz'=> 98);
  $jkl = array('arif'=>59, 'mofiz'=> 69, 'tofiz'=> 99);

  foreach ($abc as $ab):

      foreach ($def as $de):


          foreach ($ghi as $gh):
              /*** this echo prints nothing ***/
              echo $gh['arif'];
          endforeach;

          foreach ($jkl as $jk):
          endforeach;

      endforeach;

  endforeach;
```

Comment: change `echo $gh['arif']` to `echo $gh`.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, this code makes no sense. If you explain in plain english what you are trying to achieve i'll try and help you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ghi = array('arif'=>58, 'mofiz'=> 68, 'tofiz'=> 98);

foreach ($ghi as $gh):
    echo $gh['arif'];
endforeach;
```

Let's see how this is evaluated:

1. Put every element of `$ghi` into `gh` variable iteratively.
2. On first iteration `$gh` equals to 58
3. On second iteration `$gh` equals to 68
4. On third iteration `$gh` equals to 98
5. No more elements in `$ghi`, done.

That's the reason it's not printing anything - because `$gh` is not an array and doesn't have `arif` key.

I suggest you read more about [how foreach loop works](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

And I also suggest you to read a few books on code structure, especially [Clean Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882)

Comment: thnks, @Nordenheim very clean answer.  it's my problem. actually i'm wired with another thing.

Comment: i'm sorry. i actually needed to know that, is this echo valid or not?
$ghi = array('arif'=>58, 'mofiz'=> 68, 'tofiz'=> 98);

foreach ($ghi as $gh):

endforeach;
echo $gh['arif'];